# Insert User Input into a new column at end of Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

As part of a larger macro, I want to create a new column at the end of a worksheet and then fill the cells with input from an input box.

The user input is called CourseName. I'd like to add a new column at the end of the worksheet called "Course" and then fill each cell that has active data in a row with the value from CourseName.

I already have the inputBox code, and this:

```
With ActiveSheet
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this code (explanations in comments):

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' reference active sheet "used" range 
    With .Columns(.Columns.Count + 1) ' reference the column one column right of the referenced (i.e.: "used" range) range last one
        .Value = CourseName ' fill all referenced columns cell with inputbox return value (adjust "CourseName" to fit the variable name that stores InputBox return value)
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Course" 'write referenced column header
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim LastCol, LastRow As Long

'code of your inputbox, whatever it does. Mine is just to run the macro
Dim MyInputbox As String

MyInputbox = InputBox("Type something")


With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range(Cells(1, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)).Value = MyInputbox


End Sub
```

Adap it to your needs. I focused on getting always the last column and row, and type in that range whatever the value of your inputbox is.

First time I run this macro I typed "hello" and second time I typed "Hello again". As you can see, the macro goes always adds a new column with the data.

[image]

Hope this helps!